# C++11 Passing function as lambda parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, clang++

Recently, I encountered a weird problem with passing a function passed as a parameter to a lambda expression. The code compiled just fine with clang 3.5+, but failed with g++ 5.3 and I wonder whether the problem is in the c++ standard, a non-standard extension in clang, or an invalid syntactic interpretation in GCC.

The example code is fairy simple:

```
    template<typename Fn, typename... Args, typename T = typename std::result_of<Fn(Args...)>::type>
    std::future<T>
    async(Fn &&fn, Args &&... args)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<std::promise<T>> promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<T>>();
        auto lambda = [promise, fn, args...](void)
            { promise->set_value(fn(std::move(args)...)); };
        send_message(std::make_shared<post_call>(lambda));
        return promise->get_future();
    };
```

GCC reported the following:

```
error: variable ‘fn’ has function type
             { promise->set_value(fn(std::move(args)...)); };
(...)
error: field ‘async(Fn&&, Args&& ...) [with Fn = int (&)(int, int); Args = {int&, int&}; T = int]::<lambda()>::<fn capture>’ invalidly declared function type
         auto lambda = [promise, fn, args...](void)
```

Fortunately, I found a simple workaround, adding a std::function object, encapsulating the function parameter:

```
    template<typename Fn, typename... Args, typename T = typename std::result_of<Fn(Args...)>::type>
    std::future<T>
    async(Fn &&fn, Args &&... args)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<std::promise<T>> promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<T>>();
        std::function<T(typename std::remove_reference<Args>::type...)> floc = fn;
        auto lambda = [promise, floc, args...](void)
            { promise->set_value(floc(std::move(args)...)); };
        send_message(std::make_shared<post_call>(lambda));
        return promise->get_future();
    };
```

Although I don't fully understand what was wrong in the first piece of code, that successfully compiled with clang and run without errors.

---

**EDIT**

I've just noticed, that my solution fails catastrophically, if one of the arguments was supposed to be a reference. So if you have any other suggestions that might work with C++11 (i.e. without specialized lambda captures [c++14 feature]), it would be really cool...

Comment: What happens if you pass `auto p_fn = &fn` to the lambda?

Comment: @JoelCornett sigsegv or something similar. Same thing happend with passing `fn` as a reference. Though it compiles, in both cases.

Comment: @JoelCornett In concurrent/async environment passing a pointer to a scoped variable is never a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

The variable `fn` has function type.  In particular, it has type `Fn = int (&)(int, int)`.

A value of type `Fn` (not a reference) is of type `int(int,int)`.

This value cannot be stored.

I am vaguely surprised it won't auto-decay it for you.  In C++14, you can do:

```
auto lambda = [promise, fn=fn, args...](void)
        { promise->set_value(fn(std::move(args)...)); };
```

which should decay the type of `fn` (externally) to `fn` internally.  If that doesn't work:

```
auto lambda = [promise, fn=std::decay_t<Fn>(fn), args...](void)
        { promise->set_value(fn(std::move(args)...)); };
```

which explicitly decays it.  (Decay is an operation that makes a type suitable for storage).

Second, you should add `mutable`:

```
auto lambda = [promise, fn=std::decay_t<Fn>(fn), args...](void)mutable
        { promise->set_value(fn(std::move(args)...)); };
```

or the `std::move` won't do much.  (moving a const value doesn't do much).

Third, you can move the promise in instead of creating a needless shared ptr:

```
template<typename Fn, typename... Args, typename T = typename std::result_of<Fn(Args...)>::type>
std::future<T>
async(Fn &&fn, Args &&... args)
{
    std::promise<T> promise;
    std::future<T> ret = promise.get_future();
    auto lambda =
      [promise=std::move(promise), fn=std::decay_t<Fn>(fn), args...]
      () mutable {
        promise.set_value(fn(std::move(args)...));
      };
    send_message(std::make_shared<post_call>(lambda));
    return ret;
};
```

this presumes your `post_call` class can handle move-only lambdas (if it is a `std::function` it cannot).

Comment: Wow, many thanks for the advice, but unfortunately most of them require C++14, and I've decided to stick to C++11 for the project (both compilers complain about using c++14 extensions when using initialized lambda captures, while I'm trying to stick to pure c++11), so the promise must stay a pointer (though I guess it could be just normal pointer, but I'm not so sure what's going to happen in both cases, when the lambda is never going to be run...).
Will use your advice for sure, once I'm about to write something with c++1y ;)

Comment: @Marandil Move-into lambdas can be written manually as helper types (it is a bit verbose, I admit).  You can solve the decay problem by storing a copy of `fn` locally with `auto my_fn = std::forward<Fn>(fn);`, then capture `my_fn`.  Note that my C++14 version above (and yours) needlessly copies the `args...` into the lambda: this is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code compiles fine under VS2015, so i can't reproduce your problem but since you're using universal references, i would try something like :

```
template<typename Fn, typename... Args, typename T = typename std::result_of<Fn(Args...)>::type>
std::future<T> async2(Fn &&fn, Args &&... args)
{
    std::promise<T> prom;
    auto floc = std::bind(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto lambda = [&prom, floc](void)
    { prom.set_value(floc()); };
    send_message(std::make_shared<post_call>(lambda));
    return prom.get_future();
};
```